# Ninject, Linq to Sql, request scope for each controller without injecting

Tags: ninject

I recently came across this article titled:
Linq to Sql and ASP.NET MVC – DataContext Per Request
at this link:
http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/01/31/linq-to-sql-and-asp-net-mvc-datacontext-per-request/

I would like to set this up using ninject rather than structuremap preferably using the new mvc 3 dependency resolver as I'm using mvc 3 rtm.

The relevant part of the article is this:

**Firstly, you’ll need to configure StructureMap by calling ObjectFactory.Configure inside your Global.asax passing in a custom Registry instance:**

```
protected void Application_Start() {
 RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

 ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => {
  cfg.AddRegistry(new MyRegistry());
 });
}
```

**The code for MyRegistry looks like this:**

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry {
 public MyRegistry() {
  For<BlogDataContext>()
   .HttpContextScoped()
   .Use(c => new BlogDataContext());

  Scan(scan => {
   scan.AddAllTypesOf<Controller>();
  });
 }
}
```

Here I’m telling StructureMap to create one instance of my BlogDataContext per HTTP Request as well as registering each Controller instance with the container.

Next, we need to tell MVC to use StructureMap to instantiate our controllers. This can be done by creating a custom ControllerFactory:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
 protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
  return (IController) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
 }
}
```

We can then replace the DefaultControllerFactory with the StructureMapControllerFactory in our Application_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
 RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

 ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => {
  cfg.AddRegistry(new MyRegistry());
 });

 ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
  new StructureMapControllerFactory());
}
```

I would like to do the same thing with ninject 2.0 rather than structure map. I'm building an mvc 3 site with ninject mvc3. I downloaded the ninject mvc 3 package from nuget and I have this file in my solution which handles wiring up ninject.
AppStart_NinjectMVC3.cs

I do not want to use structurmap and I know the same setup can be done with ninject, but I'm unsure how to wire it up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use the official mvc3 extension from the ninject project found at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc. It comes with a full example application showing how to wire up an mvc3 application.